# Conditional probability exercise about cancer population.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I have this question.

> Suppose that there is a method to detect cancer with the property that $90\%$ of people with cancer reacts positive, while the $5\%$ of those who **don't** have cancer reacts positive. Suppose that the $1\%$ of a population has cancer. Calculate the probability that a random person selected from that population has cancer and tests positive.

My try was:

$\text{A}=\text{Reacts positive, } \text{B}=\text{Has cancer}$

$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B\mid A) P(A)}{P(B)}$$
I know that
$$P(B)=0.01,\ \ P(A)=(0.99)(0.05)+(0.01)(0.90)=0.0585$$
and by hypothesis $P(B\mid A)=.90$

So the answer must be:
$$\frac{P(B\mid A) P(A)}{P(B)}=\frac{(.90)(.01)}{.0585}=\frac{9}{585}=\frac{1}{65}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Why isn't the probability that he has cancer and reacts positively $P(A\cap B)?$  You've computed the probability that he has cancer given that he reacts positively, which sounds like a different question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking about the probability that a random person tests positive AND has cancer, you are looking for:

\begin{align*}
P(A  \cap B ) = P(A|B)P(B) =  0.9 \times 0.01 = 0.09
\end{align*}

if instead you are asking the probability that someone has cancer given they tested positive:

\begin{align*}
P(B | A ) &= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}\\
& = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}\\
& = \frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|\bar{B})P(\bar{B})}\\
&=\frac{0.9 \times 0.01}{0.9 \times 0.01 + 0.05 \times 0.99}
\end{align*}

Comment: Given that $5\%$ of those who do not have cancer test positive, shouldn't your denominator be $0.9 \cdot 0.01 + \color{red}{0.05} \cdot 0.99$?